# unable to add new user in tridion

Tags: 2013-sp1, workflow, odata

Hi Iam facing one problem add user in tridion.

we are select directory type directory service(LDAP) -> enter user id and click createUnlisted button this way added user .
but unable to login tridion.
we are trying search that user but below error is showing
(80040356) Unable to list users from
Error occurred while searching in LDAP subtree 'OU=Central,DC=corp,DC=telenor,DC=no' with filter '(sAMAccountName=*)'.
The size limit was exceeded
please help me how to add new user in tridion.

Answer (score 0):

This looks more of your Active Directory Issue.
Follow the [URL](http://searchmidmarketsecurity.techtarget.com/tip/How-to-perform-an-Active-Directory-health-check)

Check the event logs things will be more clear.